# how to use the property file with jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

i am creating jasper report. in my report instead of using the static text directly i want to use the property file that holds the static text of my jasper report. for that purpose i have created one property file that holds the text value. in the report i am using the jasper fields that appears like this

```
<textField>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="55" height="40"/>
<textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
<font size="9" isBold="true"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{c3.7}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

i have also given the path of the property file that appears in the

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["property file"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

now, when i am compiling the reprot that report will fill my fields with the null values. i suppose that the this operation is some where related to the resource bundle keys, and i am not able to figure it out properly please help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the resourceBundle attribute of your report

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" (...)  resourceBundle="PropertiesFileName">
```